# Page Class using PageFactory

Tags: java, selenium, factory-pattern, pageobjects

I am new to `PageFactory` and referring this tutorial https://www.toptal.com/selenium/test-automation-in-selenium-using-page-object-model-and-page-factory

An example from this page:

```
public class HomePage {
   private WebDriver driver;

   //Page URL
   private static String PAGE_URL="https://www.toptal.com";

   //Locators

   //Apply as Developer Button
   @FindBy(how = How.LINK_TEXT, using = "APPLY AS A DEVELOPER")
   private WebElement developerApplyButton;

   //Constructor
   public HomePage(WebDriver driver){
       this.driver=driver;
       driver.get(PAGE_URL);
       //Initialise Elements
       PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
   }

   public void clickOnDeveloperApplyButton(){

       developerApplyButton.click();

   }
}
```

1. Why create a private instance of `WebDriver`? It is appearing with yellow line for me.
2. When to use `how = HOW` and when we can straight away use `xpath= //id..`?
3. In constructor we are again passing `WebDriver` parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The yellow line is because you are not using the driver variable declared with the class but the one you are passing as the variable to the constructor. Try using :

   `this.driver.get(PAGE_URL);
   //Initialise Elements
   PageFactory.initElements(this.driver, this);`
2. You can use `xpath = "//div"` straight away when you are not using how.LINK_TEXT as you also have to provide the text for searching the link if you want to locate an element via LINK_TEXT.
3. In the constructor, you are passing the driver instance so when the page object is created, it has a driver instance as it is not the page instantiating the driver.